# Replace a simple for-loop with a recursive function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I was watching Eric Meijer's lectures on functional programming and I found this example to be really nice and intriguing:

If I had to sum a list of numbers in an *imperative* way, I would do something like:

```
total=0
for each in range(0, 10):
    total = total + each
```

where I am explaining how to do this, instead of just specifying what I want.

This expression in Python does the same thing:

```
sum(range(1,10))
```

and it is same as my original problem statement which is to "sum a list of numbers". This is a nice high-level programming language construct to have since is both readable and *declarative*.

1. `range(1,10)` captures the fact that this is a list of items.
2. `sum` captures the computation to be done.

So, my first thought was functions which return values are more useful than `for-loops` at-least in some scenarios. On further reading I also found `for-loops` are just a syntactic sugar for doing a `jump` operation which can also be replaced with a recursive function call with the proper base condition. **Is that correct statement?**

So generarlizing this, I just wrote a simple `reduce` function which looks like:

```
def reduce(operation, start, array):
    # I think I could make this an expression too.
    if len(array) == 1:
        return operation(start, array[0])
    return reduce(operation, operation(start, array[0]), array[1:])
```

I just wanted to know if this a good way to start thinking functionally i.e in terms of inputs and outputs as much as possible?

The advantage I can think of is:

1. We can create any number of partials like sum, product etc. But I think it can be implemented using loops as well.

The disadvantage is:

1. I am duplicating this array again and again. Space complexity is O(n^2). I can use indexes to avoid that problem, but the code will look messy.
2. Since there is no tail recursion in Python, it might create a huge stack. But that is an implementation detail to be aware of.

Comment: If this is more of a Software Engineering question, I can move it to there.

Comment: To answer a part of your question: Yes, you can mathematically prove that recursion and iteration are both equally powerful. You can write every possible program with just one of them.

Comment: `reduce` is already a built-in in Python 2 and available as `functools.reduce` in Python 3.

Comment: A simpler base case, by the way, is `if len(array) == 0: return start`.

Comment: @chepner, That is a nice subtle catch! I am repeating myself! It also seems like I could use the `next` somewhere if I were to do it in a Pythonic way!

Answer (score 1):

Re: Disadvantage #2

Yes it does create a huge stack. I have experienced this specifically with IronPython on Windows. If you get an error thrown deep into your number of recursions (unlikely for a simple sum, but when dealing with external APIs, it can happen) you will get a stacktrace back with an error thrown in every frame since the original call. This can make it very difficult to debug.

This code:

```
class ConnectedItem():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.connected_to = None

    def connect(self, item):
        self.connected_to = item

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<item: {} connected to {}>".format(self.name, self.connected_to)

items = []
for l in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:
    items += [ConnectedItem(l)]

for n, i in enumerate(items):
    if n < 3:
        i.connect(items[n + 1])

def recursively_access(item):
    # print(item.name)
    return recursively_access(item.connected_to)

recursively_access(items[0])
```

Produces this:

[image: unhelpful stacktrace]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly python, but recursion is a methodology that can be used in any language. Here is an example that can hopefully get you thinking along the right track.

```
recursiveMethod(param1, param2)
    if (param1 > 10)
        return from method
    recursiveMethod(param1++, param2 += whateverOperation)
```